# Change Constraint Names using an Entity Framework Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I have built a database using EF Codefirst (In an MVC4 application).

I've since learnt, that an external tool that will access this database has name-length limitations for columns & constraints.

1. Column names must be <=20 chars
2. Constraint names muse be <=10 chars

I'm therefor required to change the names of the generated DB constraints. (None of my column names exceed the limitation.)

Can I achieve this without destruction?
Does the migration framework provide the tools I need for such an operation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Entity framework code first does not use the constraint name in its EntityTypeConfiguration. You should be able to rename the constraint to anything you like and just mention the relationships using the properties of your entities. This is how a configuration normally looks like.

```
// Relationships
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Project)
                .WithMany(t => t.ProjectInstances)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProjectId);
```

There is this handy little tool from entity framework team called Entity Framework Power Tools. You can generate the Code first entities and mappings by using that. You can use that tool in some test project and look at the generated code. I am pretty sure you will not have any issues even if you rename your constraints as long as you give the properties correctly.